# Kohana 3.2 ORM multiple records update

Tags: kohana

How can I update multiple records in Kohana 3.2's ORM?

For example this:

```
$menu = ORM::factory('menu');
$menu->where('active','=',1);
$menu->active=2;
$menu->save();
```

does not work, it inserts a new record.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you would like to do this using ORM and not query builder?

Comment: Because, the applications is alredy using "Model_Menu extends ORM" class.

Comment: This is not an argument. Kohana's ORM is based on query builder, so it only supports a subset of query builder features. Using raw query builder you would be able to set what you need with a single SQL query instead of using separate queries for each record. The only reasonable arguments here for using ORM instead of query builder would be: 1) readability concern (executing task on ORM layer instead of lower, query builder layer), 2) custom business logic enclosed within model (eg. within `save()` method). Which one is the case here?

Comment: Thanks for the information was helpful.I will rewrite the model.

Comment: I did not propose rewriting the models - I only stated that they may be helpful somehow, but in this it may be more efficient to do it using Kohana's query builder. ORM is just an abstraction layer - if you need it, then do not switch. We havetoo few details to help you.

Comment: it should actually be $menu->where('active','=',1)->find(); if the record is one, and ->find_all() if there are many records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to hardcode the table name maybe something like below

```
DB::update(ORM::factory('menu')->table_name())
->set(array('active' => '2'))
->where('active', '=', '1')
->execute();
```